# Как вывести только те значения которые не повторяются Java Script

Tags: javascript

Есть простой массив  const arr = [6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6] // на выходе должно быть 2,4

Знаю как решить через filtr, но хочется и другие варианты , например через for или reduce.
Но как-то не получается, фот мои наброски:

```js
const arr = [6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6];
let res = [];
let count = 0;
for (el of arr) {
  console.log("el", el, "arr.indexOf(el)", arr.indexOf(el), "count", count);
  if (arr.indexOf(el)===count) {
    res.push(el);
  }
  count++;
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Например с помощью [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) и цикла `forEach`:

```js
const arr = [6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6],
  res = [];

arr.forEach(e => arr.indexOf(e) == arr.lastIndexOf(e) ? res.push(e) : {})

console.log(res);
```

или [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) и [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const arr = [6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, e) => (arr.indexOf(e) == arr.lastIndexOf(e) ? acc.push(e) : {}, acc), [])

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Как вариант, Спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - решение "в лоб":

```js
const arr = [6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6];
var counters = {};
for (el of arr) {
  if (counters[el] == undefined) {
    counters[el] = 1;
  } else {
    counters[el]++;
  }
}
for (key in counters) {
  if (counters[key] == 1) {
    console.log(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Еще, можно заменить if-else на `counters[el] = ( counters[el] || 0 ) + 1;` )

Comment: Если человек задает подобные вопросы, то ему следует дать самый простой и очевидный ответ. Кмк, мой способ наиболее читаемый. Что не отменяет правильности других способов, и вашего в том числе

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с reduce:

```js
const arr = [6, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6];

const result = arr.reduce((acc,item) => {
  if(acc.includes(item)) { //если находим повторяющийся элемент
    acc.splice(acc.indexOf(item),1); //удаляем его
    return acc;
  }
  return acc.concat(item);
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: если повторений больше 2-х будет беда

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, не больше двух, а нечётное число повторений :) С чётным работает =)

Comment: точно !) не подумал об етом )

Comment: Подскажите, почему concat, а не push? И может подскажите, какая тогда разница concat или push в данном примере.

Comment: @Alexandr, потому что concat при добавлении элемента возвращает новый массив, а push - число (длину нового массива). Если в данном случае заменить concat на push, возникнет ошибка.

Comment: @humster_spb, Не ругайте, я только учусь) Но ведь можно было заменить так:   acc.push(item)
  return acc. Я просто читал, что метод пуш более производителен чем конкат или нет? Я понимаю, что в данном масштабе не имеет значения.

Comment: @Alexandr, да ну, что Вы - с чего мне ругаться? :) Я сам не то, чтобы профи. Я учился функциональному программированию по курсам hexlet - там в примерах был concat, я как-то его и использую. Конечно, можно сделать и так, как Вы предлагаете - результат в данном случае будет тот же.

Comment: @humster_spb как вам курсы hexlet ? Все понятно, все ли зашло? Как с поддержкой?

Comment: @Alexandr, не, мне с нуля - не очень. Имхо, это уже для людей, имеющих опыт в программировании, но решивших изучить другой язык, сменить направление. Объяснения, вроде, понятные, но как переходишь к практике (особенно по мере углубления курса), то ничего толком сам сделать не можешь. И очень мало дриллинговых задачек, на которых можно было бы просто набить руку. Так что я в какой-то момент бросил: время и деньги тратятся, а прогресс о-о-очень слабый. Но это моё личное мнение :)) Кому-то, наверное, хорошо заходит. p.s. В поддержку к ним ни разу не обращался